# Is there a way to rename Strong Parameter keys?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

Lets say I had code in a controller that did not use Strong Parameters

```
Model.create name: params[:name], alias_id: params[:foreign_id]
```

Is it possible for me to use Strong Parameters here?

I cannot do

```
Model.create params.require(:name, :foreign_id)
```

Because foreign_id is not a param

I cannot do

```
Model.create params.require(:name, :alias_id)
```

Because alias_id is not on the model.

Basically, I want to know if you can alias paramater keys when using Strong Parameters.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Usually if I want to map params in this way (usually due to some external API) I use the `alias_attribute` method in `ActiveRecord`

So if I have params that come to me as `{name: "bob", alias_id: 1234}` and ideally I would want to have `{name: "bob", foreign_id: 1234}`

I declare the following in my `ActiveRecord` model

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  alias_attribute :alias_id, :foreign_id
end
```

Now my model will always recognise `alias_id` as mapping to `foreign_id` in any context and I can push in `params.require(:name, :alias_id)` and my model will recognise it and process it as required without looping over attributes in my controller.

This is also simpler if you want to do it on other models as well.

Comment: TIL. Thank you for the insight!

Comment: This mutates the model, not the params.  Now the model knows about the controller.

Comment: @baash05 No, the model simply has knowledge of other names or aliases for its own attributes and that of the API's model. alias_attribute is a valid method in ActiveRecord which requires no gems or external dependencies. The controller is not involved in this at all. This is a local model mimicking an external model. solving this in the controller is the controller knowing about the model!

Answer (score 3):

I got the functionality I wanted with the following piece of code.  I don't think Strong Parameters can do what I need, especially as require() cannot take multiple parameters.

By putting this in my ApplicationController or a module it inherits

```
#
# Pass in a list of param keys to pull out of the params object
# Alias param keys to another key by specifiying a mapping with a Hash
# eg.  filter_params :foo, :bar, {:choo => :zoo}
#
def filter_params(*param_list)
  filtered_params = {}
  param_list.each do |param|
    if param.is_a? Hash
      param.each {|key, value| filtered_params[value] = params[key]}
    else
      filtered_params[param] = params[param]
    end
  end
  filtered_params
end
```

I can now say

```
Model.create filter_params(:name, {foreign_id: :alias_id})
```